# AJAX error Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403 to Spring

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

I want run POST AJAX but I found an error > Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403. I created POST method in Spring and I want consume with AJAX (I use SAPUI5 frontend based on javascript).

[Error and Invalid CORS Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R686w.png)

[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kseu5.png)

Log when run spring (maven project):

```
org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$793b4734]
> is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for
> example: not eligible for auto-proxying) [INFO] Loaded JDBC driver:
> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver [INFO] HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons
> Annotations {4.0.5.Final} [INFO] HHH000412: Hibernate Core
> {4.3.11.Final} [INFO] HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found [INFO]
> HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist [INFO] HHH000400: Using
> dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect [INFO] HHH000423:
> Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version
> 2 less than 4 [INFO] HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy
> (direct JDBC transactions) [INFO] HHH000397: Using
> ASTQueryTranslatorFactory [INFO] Mapped
> "{[/tesupdate],methods=[PUT],consumes=[application/json]}" onto public
> org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?>
> com.project.maven.controller.UserController.update(com.project.maven.entity.KasusEntity)
> throws java.lang.Exception [INFO] Mapped
> "{[/tesinsert],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json]}" onto
> public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?>
> com.project.maven.controller.UserController.insert(com.project.maven.entity.KasusEntity)
> throws java.lang.Exception [INFO] Mapped "{[/**],methods=[OPTIONS]}"
> onto public void
> com.project.maven.controller.UserController.corsHeaders(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
> [INFO] Mapped "{[/tesget],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List
> com.project.maven.controller.UserController.getTes2() throws
> java.lang.Exception [INFO] Mapped
> "{[/v2/api-docs],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json ||
> application/hal+json]}" onto public
> org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json>
> springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
> [INFO] Mapped "{[/swagger-resources/configuration/security]}" onto
> org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SecurityConfiguration>
> springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.securityConfiguration()
> [INFO] Mapped "{[/swagger-resources/configuration/ui]}" onto
> org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.swagger.web.UiConfiguration>
> springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.uiConfiguration()
> [INFO] Mapped "{[/swagger-resources]}" onto
> org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SwaggerResource>>
> springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.swaggerResources()
> [INFO] Mapped URL path [/static/**] onto handler of type [class
> org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
> [INFO] Mapped URL path [/**/**] onto handler of type [class
> org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
> [INFO] Looking for @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext:
> startup date [Tue Jun 06 10:22:39 ICT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
> [INFO] Using DataSource
> [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@1dafa047]
> of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager [INFO]
> Starting beans in phase 2147483647 [INFO] Context refreshed [INFO]
> Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s) [INFO] Scanning for api listing
> references [INFO] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed
> in 7923 ms Jun 06, 2017 10:22:47 AM
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: Initializing
> Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet' [INFO] FrameworkServlet
> 'appServlet': initialization started [INFO] Refreshing
> WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date
> [Tue Jun 06 10:22:47 ICT 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
> [INFO] Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource
> [/WEB-INF/config/servlet-context.xml] [INFO] FrameworkServlet
> 'appServlet': initialization completed in 50 ms Jun 06, 2017 10:22:47
> AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: Initializing
> Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher' [INFO] FrameworkServlet
> 'dispatcher': initialization started [INFO] Refreshing
> WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date
> [Tue Jun 06 10:22:47 ICT 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
> [INFO] Registering annotated classes: [class
> com.project.maven.config.AppConfig] [INFO] JSR-330
> 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
> [INFO] Bean
> 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration'
> of type [class
> org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$793b4734]
> is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for
> example: not eligible for auto-proxying) [INFO] Loaded JDBC driver:
> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver [INFO] HHH000400: Using dialect:
> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect [INFO] HHH000423: Disabling
> contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version 2 less
> than 4 [INFO] HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct
> JDBC transactions) [INFO] HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
> [INFO] Mapped
> "{[/tesupdate],methods=[PUT],consumes=[application/json]}" onto public
> org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?>
> com.project.maven.controller.UserController.update(com.project.maven.entity.KasusEntity)
> throws java.lang.Exception [INFO] Mapped
> "{[/tesinsert],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json]}" onto
> public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?>
> com.project.maven.controller.UserController.insert(com.project.maven.entity.KasusEntity)
> throws java.lang.Exception [INFO] Mapped "{[/**],methods=[OPTIONS]}"
> onto public void
> com.project.maven.controller.UserController.corsHeaders(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
> [INFO] Mapped "{[/tesget],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List
> com.project.maven.controller.UserController.getTes2() throws
> java.lang.Exception [INFO] Mapped
> "{[/v2/api-docs],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json ||
> application/hal+json]}" onto public
> org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json>
> springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
> [INFO] Mapped "{[/swagger-resources/configuration/security]}" onto
> org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SecurityConfiguration>
> springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.securityConfiguration()
> [INFO] Mapped "{[/swagger-resources/configuration/ui]}" onto
> org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.swagger.web.UiConfiguration>
> springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.uiConfiguration()
> [INFO] Mapped "{[/swagger-resources]}" onto
> org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SwaggerResource>>
> springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.swaggerResources()
> [INFO] Using DataSource
> [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@3afb8a87]
> of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager [INFO]
> Mapped URL path [/static/**] onto handler of type [class
> org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
> [INFO] Mapped URL path [/**/**] onto handler of type [class
> org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
> [INFO] Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for
> namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue Jun 06 10:22:47 ICT
> 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext [INFO] Starting beans in
> phase 2147483647 [INFO] Context refreshed [INFO] Found 1 custom
> documentation plugin(s) [INFO] Scanning for api listing references
> [INFO] FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 1351
> ms Jun 06, 2017 10:22:48 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
> INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8089"]
```

Controller in Spring:

```
@PostMapping(value={"/tesinsert"}, consumes={"application/json"})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public ResponseEntity<?> insert(@RequestBody KasusEntity user) throws Exception {
    Map result = new HashMap();
    userService.insertTabel(user);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

in javascript:

```
    var data = {
            "kodekasus":5,
            "nama":"baru",
            "isdelete":1,
            "createdby":"hahaa",
            "createddate":null,
            "updatedby":"hihii",
            "updateddate":null
    };

    var url = "http://localhost:8089/SpringNew/tesinsert";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data), 
        success: function(data) { 
            console.log('sukses: '+data); 
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log('gagal: '+error);
            console.log(data);
        }
        ,
        headers: {
            Accept : "application/json",
            "Content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
            }
    });
```

How to solve this problem? Where code is wrong? in javascript or spring? I already try run insert method in spring with Swagger and I can insert data. I already try ajax GET and no problem. Before this, I also found a problem with AJAX GET but I solved this problem with clear "contentType" in ajax. but in AJAX POST cannot.

Thanks.

Bobby

Comment: In your ajax call no need of .stringify(data), just  data: data,

Comment: I already try without stringify but show the same error.

Comment: can you able to show your Entity class(KasusEntity)

Comment: Okay Kalai. I write entity class below this comment.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

this my code in KasusEntity:

```
package com.project.maven.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="KASUS")
public class KasusEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="KODE_KASUS")
    private int kodekasus;

    @Column(name="NAMA")
    private String nama;

    @Column(name="IS_DELETE")
    private int isdelete;   

    @Column(name="CREATED_BY")
    private String createdby;   

    @Column(name="CREATED_DATE")
    private Date createddate;       

    @Column(name="UPDATED_BY")
    private String updatedby;

    @Column(name="UPDATED_DATE")
    private Date updateddate;

    public int getKodekasus() {
        return kodekasus;
    }

    public void setKodekasus(int kodekasus) {
        this.kodekasus = kodekasus;
    }

    public String getNama() {
        return nama;
    }

    public void setNama(String nama) {
        this.nama = nama;
    }

    public int getIsdelete() {
        return isdelete;
    }

    public void setIsdelete(int isdelete) {
        this.isdelete = isdelete;
    }

    public String getCreatedby() {
        return createdby;
    }

    public void setCreatedby(String createdby) {
        this.createdby = createdby;
    }

    public Date getCreateddate() {
        return createddate;
    }

    public void setCreateddate(Date createddate) {
        this.createddate = createddate;
    }

    public String getUpdatedby() {
        return updatedby;
    }

    public void setUpdatedby(String updatedby) {
        this.updatedby = updatedby;
    }

    public Date getUpdateddate() {
        return updateddate;
    }

    public void setUpdateddate(Date updateddate) {
        this.updateddate = updateddate;
    }

}
```

Thanks.
Bobby